# Editing gdal_translate when scripted?

Tags: python, gdal

I'm relatively new to python scripting and I'm trying to batch process a number of files, with the first command being to convert formats.

```
gdal_translate -of KEA NDVI_20160101.tif NDVI_20160101.KEA
```

works perfectly when inputting the command directly into the terminal but when I copy and paste the command into a text editor and try and run the script from the destination with:

```
python ./SCRIPT_NAME.py
```

I get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: What happens when you run your `SCRIPT_NAME.py` from an IDE like IDLE?  I would expect it to tell you the line on which you have a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[os.system()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) and [os.popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.popen)() have been deprecated since Python 2.6 in favor of the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module (for various reasons), see [Calling gdal utilities from within python using subprocess](http://chris35wills.github.io/subprocess_gdal/).

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('gdal_translate -of AAIGrid KEA NDVI_20160101.tif NDVI_20160101.KEA', shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this directly like that. If you want to run command in Python you should use:

```
import os
os.system("gdal_translate -of KEA NDVI_20160101.tif NDVI_20160101.KEA ")
```

Comment: This would work but the consensus is to now use subprocess.call